# Cocoa: Could a NSview be displayed on its own?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch

I created a Cocoa view with Controller. I added a few buttons to the view and established actions and outlets inn the controller. Now, I am trying to display the view. How do I display it?
The Display() method does not display the view

Answer (score 0):

You ask:

> Cocoa: Could a NSview be displayed on its own?

Apple's [View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH1-SW1) starts with the sentence:

> A view instance is responsible for drawing and responding to user actions in a rectangular region of a window.

HTH